# share a project to svn

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I am not sure how to share a project in Apache Subversion (SVN).
I created an SVN repository named `testsvn` on Ubuntu linux.

I am running Eclipse IDE on another Windows system where I have installed Subclipse and 
I want to share Eclipse project with the Subversion.

E.g. **Team | Share project | SVN | Create a new repository**

Then I give the url as `http://192.168.10.1/testsvn` but I get an error as

```
svn: E175002: connection refused by the server
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/testsvn'
```

Can anyone help me how to fix the problem..

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

We encountered the same error from our SVN server when running an ANT script to perform an automated checkout.  My initial thought was that anonymous reads were disallowed but that didn't make sense considering our configuration.  Here was our console output:

```
  [svn] svn: E175002: connection refused by the server
  [svn] svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/branch_201212131157_3.1.6'
  [svn] Connection refused: connect
  [svn] <Checkout> failed.
```

It turned out the host URL our ANT client was attempting to connect on was https:// when we weren't offering SSL on the SVN server.  This was an internal server but providing the full domain name with the host was also added to the URL.  Although, the relative hostname (name of the machine) alone should have been sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You should add your svn repository URL in  **New** > **SVN Repository** but not create a new one in **Team** > **Share Project** (apparently, you cannot create it remotely). See step by step instructions [here](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/subclipse/).

Comment: yes but I already have a project , which I want to share..I tried to use point 5 of the step by step instructions u gave.. I am not sure if I am giving the url correct..

Comment: and when I try to create a new>svn repository and use the url http://192.168.10.1/testsvn/trunk I get an error 'folder doesnot exist remotely'.